# How to print to console return value of each line of code in an ajax function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, error-handling

I want to see the return value of each line of code in an ajax function. The below code gives me error 1 and e. Now I want to check exactly what is causing the error by printing the return value of each line of the function.
Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function editTitleModalSubmit(titleId) {
    console.log("1");
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'functions/administration-functions.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { "title": $('#editadminTitle').val(), "units": $('#editadminUnits').val(), "category": $('#editadminCategory').val(), "titleId": $('#adminTitleId').val(), "typeId": $('#adminTypeId').val() },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {
            $('#adminForm').trigger('reset');
            resultAlert('#adminResult', '#resultAdminContent', '<strong>You data was succefully saved!</strong>', 'alert-success');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("e");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

administration-functions.php

```
<?php
    require_once './queries.php';
    $title   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "title");
    $units    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "units");
    $category = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "category");
    $typeId   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "typeId");
    $titleId  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "titleId");
    echo Queries::editTitle($title, $units, $category, $titleId, $typeId);
?>
```

Comment: What you could do is execute your function within your console and make use of [breakpoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint) and check what values your backend returns to you.

Comment: It prints the error 1 and e to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't assigning the failure to anything and are reading `e` as a string. Try replacing the error part of your code with this:

```
error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Indeed the `"e"` part within your `console.log("e")` is considered a hard coded string. It will never contain your error unless you would be using a field to return the error like atoms presents above.

Comment: This gave me detailed error. Somewhat close to what I was looking for. Thanks :)